# Can I pass TWO user defined objects (as JSON) to web method in ASP?

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, webmethod

**Object Types:**

Public Class X

```
Public p1 As Boolean

Public p2 As String

Public p3 As String
```

End Class

Public Class Y

```
Public p1 As Boolean

Public p2 As String

Public p3 As String
```

End Class

**Web Method:**

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function saveObject(obj As X) As Integer 

    ' stuff

End Function
```

**Ajax:**

> var obj  = { p1: value, p2: value, p3: value };  //object 1 which I
>   successfully sent alone
>
> var obj2 = { p1: value, p2: value, p3: value };  //object 2 that I
>   want to send it together with object 1
>
> . . .
>
> . . .
>
> data: JSON.stringify({ 'obj': obj }), //the data in AJAX call, which
>   works perfectly with one object

**Now I want to send obj2 (type Y) with obj1 (type X)...**

**Is there a way to do this or is it impossible??**

I tried everything I know, but I keep getting errors in AJAX call or no response at all.

Comment: create a class that containing both the classes you want to send and use that class in the ajax request

Comment: @geo, good idea! I'll try it

Comment: @geo, absolutely great! your idea worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a container class that contains the classes that you need to send as properties and use that class in the Ajax request.

```
Public Class X
    Public P1 As Boolean
    Public P2 As String
    Public P3 As String
End Class

Public Class Y
    Public P1 As Boolean
    Public P2 As String
    Public P3 As String
End Class
```

Create a container class with properties of classes `X` and `Y`

```
Public Class Z
    Public XObj As X
    Public YObj As Y
End Class
```

Then modify your web method with an object of  class `Z` as parameter.

```
<WebMethod> _
Public Shared Function saveObject(obj As Z) As Integer 
       // stuff 
End Function
```

Now in your Ajax request modify the code as

```
var xObj = { p1: value, p2: value, p3: value }; // object of class X
var yObj = { p1: value, p2: value, p3: value }; // object of class Y

var zObj = {xObj: xObj, yObj:yObj}; // object of class Z that contains objects of classes X and Y

data = JSON.stringify({'obj':zObj}); // send this object of class Z as data.
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT :

Okay, so here is my javascript where i create my object and sent it with ajax to my controller :

```
       $(document).ready(function () {


    //My test values
    var value = "test";
    var valueBool = true

    //The array
    var arrayObj = new Array();

    //My two obj
    var obj = { p1: valueBool, p2: value, p3: value };
    var obj2 = { p1: valueBool, p2: value, p3: value };

    //Add in the array
    arrayObj.push(obj);
    arrayObj.push(obj2);


        //Display before send it 
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayObj));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/SendObj',
            data: { 'objArray': JSON.stringify(arrayObj) },
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (result) {

                if (result === "OK") {


                 console.log("Success");
                }
               else
                {
                console.log("Not good");

                }

            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {

            }
        });     

});
```

Here is my controller, tested in a c# mvc project :

```
    public string SendObj(string objArray)
    {

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(objArray))
        {
         List<Y> objs =   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Y>>(objArray);
           //Here you have your list of objects, 1 or more , as you wish, do what you want to do with them.

            return "OK";
        }

        return "KO";


    }
```

And then the class Y that i used for this test :

```
       public class Y
    {


        public Boolean p1;

        public String p2;

        public String p3;

    }
```

You send your data with json, there is no other way when you work from client to server. Then you work with your objects in your controller, and convert them from string to your specific class.

Comment: But how should the method signature look like? I tried to make it receive  an array of "Object" and tried list of "Object" but it didn't work

Comment: @AbeerSul  
If you send JSON with your ajax and hope that you'll get a different datetype in your server controller, you'll have a bad time ... Sending JSON is sending 'string'. I edited my answer with fully functionnal code :)

Comment: sorry for the delay, I got busy. I tried it but I didn't get any errors nor did the web method get called.. I don't want to say it didn't work. I'll try again with your code and I'll mark it as correct hopefully

Comment: It have to works, you just send a string to your server with ajax, that's a basic thing for a website. It could be : ajax is not installed, the path write in your javascript is not correct. I edited my answer , i written "Uploads/SendObj" because my controller was called UploadsController. You'll have to write your own path to your webmethod, and maybe c# to VB is different, i'm better in c# sorry